# How to enable "show method chain hint" in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, reactive-programming

I am using JDK 8 and using reactive programming(spring webflux). I want to know how to enable "show method chain hint" in IntelliJ ?

Comment: What version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: Do you have [this option](https://i.imgur.com/H3RBbIR.png) enabled?

Comment: @JacobG.  Below is the version details. IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.4323.46, built on September 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: @CrazyCoder, yes that option is enabled already.

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable this option? When I search for "chain" within IntelliJ nothing appears but I still get those hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IntelliJ 2019.3, one should set for inlay hints (in Settings | Editor | Inlay hints | Java):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to: **Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > show chain call type hints**

[image: chain hints in intellij]

To disable you can just right-click any hint and disable from there